# sql query to count same records between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

sql query to count records between two tables

```
Table 1

sub_id
------
11
22
33
44



Table 2

txt_id      sub_id
------------------
1            11   
2            11
3            33
4            33
5            33
6            22
```

i want sql query to count sub_id from Table2
so the result will be

```
sub_id    count
---------------
11          2
22          1
33          3
44          0
```

i have done it with php using loops but this way will be too slow
i prefer to execute it in 1 sql query

Comment: Show us first what you have tried to solve the problem. SO isn't a 'solve my problem' site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.sub_id, count(*) 
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id 
GROUP BY t1.sub_id;
```

Google sql aggregate functions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @lxg may be you are just jealous that he answered before you ?

Comment: @Begueradj: I never even had the intention to reply to this post. The answer was in the moderation queue for low quality, and the comment was generated from a template.

Comment: @lxg I was just kidding :) Have a nice day.

Comment: you ignored Table1 in your query